# Selenium standalone 2.45.0; Scripts crash Firefox 38.0.1

Tags: java, windows, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have used 2.44 with an earlier version of Firefox - it was working fine.

```
FirefoxDriver ffd = new FirefoxDriver();
ffd.get("www.google.com");
```

Now, even this simple invocation throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: f.QueryInterface is not a function
Command duration or timeout: 190 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'Shivam-PC', ip: '192.168.0.107', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=38.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 19f3d00e-ad14-4fc8-9d29-cee47ae44186
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:304)
    at sele.Sample.main(Sample.java:13)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: f.QueryInterface is not a function
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'Shivam-PC', ip: '192.168.0.107', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.get(file:///C:/Users/Shivam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4862788616202211612webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10132)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/Shivam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4862788616202211612webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12274)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Shivam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4862788616202211612webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12279)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/Shivam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4862788616202211612webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12221)
```

Comment: Sounds like a compatibility issue. Downgrade firefox to 35.0.1.

Comment: Same problem for me when Firefix was upgraded to 38.0.1. I downgraded to the earlier 37, which worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be common problem from version to version (I faced such kind of problem with FF v.36). Main work around is DO NOT update FF to the newest version (or downgrade if the worst already happened).  If your tests work well with particular FF version -> stick with it at least till new version of WebDriver is released.

For myself the most reliable version is FF v.33.

Comment: Check Selenium 2.46.0 release [note](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) first. You can download FF33 from Mozilla [ftp](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/33.0/win32/en-US/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the most robust solution for dealing with Selenium tests on Firefox is to stick with the latest ESR ([Extended Support Release](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/)) which is mentioned in their [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG) file. The Selenium team has to keep up with the changes introduced in Firefox and that may naturally lead to problems with the most recent versions here and there - [not much has changed since the Selenium RC days in this respect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945108).

**Update 2016-01-18:** There are now *two* ESR releases mentioned in the CHANGELOG, since with Firefox 33, support for native events has been dropped in favor of synthetic events. The wiki [states](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions#Native_events_versus_synthetic_events):

> Native events simulate the user interactions better whereas synthetic
>   events are platform independent, which can be important in Linux when
>   alternative window managers are used, see [native events on Linux](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/NativeEventsOnLinux).
>   Native events should be used whenever it is possible.

So depending on your OS, you might try both versions to find the one better suited for you:

- For native events: Firefox [31.7.0ESR](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/31.7.0esr/)
- For synthetic events: Firefox [38.5.2ESR](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/38.5.2esr/)

Last mention was in Selenium 2.47.0 and included Firefox versions 31, 38 and 39.

If you want to use the latest ESR release no matter what, Mozilla provides a [link for that](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/latest-esr/README.txt), too.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to your url...change it to **http://www.google.com** or **https://www.google.com**

Hope this fixes your problem...Kindly get back if you have any queries